# How to check if a database exists?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to check if a database is working as a "Publisher" to other databases.

To do this I was planing on checking if the database "distribution" exists on that instance.

after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450482/how-to-check-if-a-database-exists-with-odbc) I thought I could just do

```
new Sqlcommand("SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = @name")
```

and solve my problem...but I dont have that table in my database...:s

is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: nvm found it in sys instead of dbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if a database is a publisher then looking for a distributor is the wrong check. A database can have a *remote* distributor, in which case you'll get a false negative. Or the distributor may exist but the database may not be a publisher, in which case you get a false positive. Not to mention that the distribution DB may have **any** name, so looking for a database named `distribution` is also wrong.

The proper way to do it is to sue the built in replication helper procedures:

- [`exec sp_helppublication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189782.aspx) will return information about all publications in a database. IF the database is not a publisher, it won't return anything (yoru cue to action).
- [`exec sp_helpdistributor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177504.aspx) will return information about the distributor of a publisher
- [`exec sp_helpdistributiondb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187725.aspx) will return information about a distribution database

In addition, the simple facts whether the DB is a publisher, subscriber or distributor can be discovered in [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx):

> - **is_published** Database is a publication database in a
>     transactional or snapshot replication topology.
> - **is_merge_published** Database is a publication database in a merge replication topology.
> - **is_subscribed** Database is a subscription database in a
>     replication topology.
> - **is_distributor** Database is the distribution
>     database for a replication topology.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have sufficient permissions to view database metadata you can use

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN DB_ID('distribution') IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END AS distributionExists
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from sys.databases
where name = @name
```

Very close.  It looks like that is SQL Server 2000 catalog view.  What you are looking for is querying `sys.databases`.